# Updating a record in a modal with laravel, not saving

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update records in the mysql database with laravel through a bootstrap modal. Here's how I have collected data from the table of records,

```
<button class="site-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".edit-booking"  data-bookingid="{{ $records->id }}" data-firstname="{{ $records->firstname }}" data-lastname="{{ $records->lastname }}" data-roomtype="{{ $records->roomtype }}" data-checkin="{{ $records->checkin }}" data-checkout="{{ $records->checkout }}" data-adults="{{ $records->adults }}" data-children="{{ $records->children }}" data-email="{{ $records->email }}" data-phone="{{ $records->phone }}" data-payment="{{ $records->payment }}" data-additionals="{{ $records->additionals }}" data-address="{{ $records->address }}"><span class="fa fa-edit"> Edit</span></button> / <button class="site-button"><span class="fa fa-trash"> Delete</span></button>
```

My modal for editing,

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-secondry">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title text-black">Edit Booking</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body edit-modal-body">
          <div class="section-content">
          <!-- CONTACT FORM-->
          <div class="wt-box">
            <form class="contact-form" id="edit-form" action="{{route('booking.update',$records->id)}}" name="edit-form" method="post"> {{method_field('patch')}} {{csrf_field()}}
              <div class="contact-one p-a40 p-r150">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input name="editbookingid" id="editbookingid" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_firstname">First Name</label>
                  <input name="edit_firstname" id="edit_firstname" type="text" required class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_lastname">Last Name</label>
                  <input name="edit_lastname" type="text" id="edit_lastname" required class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_email">Email</label>
                  <input name="edit_email" type="email" id="edit_email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_phone">Phone</label>
                  <input name="edit_phone" type="phone" id="edit_phone" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="edit_address">Address</label>
                  <textarea name="edit_address" id="edit_address" rows="3" class="form-control " required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_roomtype">Room type</label>
                  <input name="edit_roomtype" id="edit_roomtype" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="two-columns-row">
                  <div class="form-group two-columns">
                    <label for="edit_adults">Adults</label>
                    <input type="text" name="edit_adults" id="edit_adults" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group two-columns">
                    <label for="edit_children">Children</label>
                    <input type="text" name="edit_children" id="edit_children" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="two-columns-row">
                  <div class="form-group two-columns">
                    <label for="edit_checkin">Check-in Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="edit_checkin" id="edit_checkin" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group two-columns">
                    <label for="edit_check-out">Check-out Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="edit_checkout" id="edit_checkout" class="form-control" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_payment">Payment Method</label>
                  <input name="edit_payment" type="text" id="edit_payment" required class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="edit_additionals">Additional Notes</label>
                  <textarea name="edit_additionals" rows="3" id="edit_additionals" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="site-button black radius-no text-uppercase" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="site-button black radius-no text-uppercase" name="edit_submit">Save Changes</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Script used to fill the modal,

```
<script>
  /* For filling data in the edit modal */
  $('.edit-booking').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var recordid = button.data('bookingid')
    var firstname = button.data('firstname')
    var lastname = button.data('lastname')
    var roomtype = button.data('roomtype')
    var checkin = button.data('checkin') 
    var checkout = button.data('checkout')
    var adults = button.data('adults')
    var children = button.data('children')
    var email = button.data('email')
    var phone = button.data('phone')
    var payment = button.data('payment')
    var additionals = button.data('additionals')
    var address = button.data('address') 
    var modal = $(this)

    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #editbookingid').val(recordid);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_firstname').val(firstname);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_lastname').val(lastname);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_roomtype').val(roomtype);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_checkin').val(checkin);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_checkout').val(checkout);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_adults').val(adults);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_children').val(children);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_email').val(email);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_phone').val(phone);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_payment').val(payment);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_additionals').val(additionals);
    modal.find('.edit-modal-body #edit_address').val(address);
  })
</script>
```

This is my update() in the controller,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $an_update = Bookings::findOrFail($id);
        $an_update->update($request->all());
        return back();
    }
```

and this is the model,

```
class Bookings extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'adults', 'children', 'checkin', 'checkout', 'additionals', 'roomtype', 'payment'];
}
```

After filling all the changes in the form, if I click "save changes", the page reloads but the record is not updated at all.

Comment: Can you list the debugging steps you have taken so far? For example is the $request being filled with the data you are expecting? is $id being populated correctly? Have you read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask yet?

Comment: Yes the $request is filled with the expected data, I checked it with dd($request->all()), the id is populated properly as well, and I read the instructions on how to ask and did what I can.

Comment: Did your modal return the record for the id?

Comment: Yes, all the fields in the modal were populated with values of the correct record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks to me the way you are assigning the values from the request is what is wonky. I haven't tested this personally yet, in a bit of a rush. Will come back and update this answer in a few hours. In the mean time, give this a try.

```
$an_update = Bookings::findOrFail($id);
$an_update->firstName = $request->input('customer_license_plate');
$ticket->save();

return back();
```

Do that for all your records fields, remember that back() will redirect the user back to the page they came from regardless of a success or fail. You may wish to consider additional logic to redirect to another page upon success (like a listing screen for example).

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates

Comment: What should I put in place of "customer_license_plate"?

Comment: Hey, I rewrote my update() according to the example given in the mass updates section of the docs, removed the id parameter from the update() and collected id from the $request and finally it is working now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

$id is assigned from a route parameter, but your route is being defined in your form action prior to the modal being opened.  You don't appear to be updating the booking ID of the route anywhere when you open the modal.

This means you're always updating the booking with an ID of `$records->id`, whatever that value is.

Comment: Yep, I found that bug and fixed it. Thanks for letting me know. :-)

Comment: Actually, the solution given by @RyanFletcher worked for me. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Using update() is perfectly fine, so I'm not sure how that answer solved anything.  Most Laravel devs would promote the use of update() so just hacking it together instead of learning to do it the right way probably isn't the best way to get yourself familiar with the conventions of the framework.

Comment: I followed the docs and that's how I solved my problem, that's it.